# How to do navigation between two views using JS view in openui5 for desktop application?

Tags: sapui5

As I am a newbie to openui5, I can't navigate from one view to another view using a button click.

How do I do that? I searched a lot and I got frustrated. While searching mostly I got the data related to `sap.m(mobile)` but I need code sample for `sap.ui.commons(desktop)` or any other link would be helpful.

Can anyone share some sample code for `sap.ui.commons` (Routing or tab navigation) not for `sap.m`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Router](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html) of the SAPUI5 Application:

Sample code snippet :

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.routing.Router.getRouter("appRouter");
//can also use directly this.oRouter.navTo if you're extending scaffloding OR base controllers of SAP UI5.
oRouter.navTo("samplePattern",oContext,false);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are different options for this:

**1.Option:**

is to use the `sap.ui.ux3.Shell` see [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.ux3.Shell.html)

**2.Option:**

using a [Router](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html)

**3.Option:**

or by hiding a view and showing it like this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('View1').setVisible(false);
sap.ui.getCore().byId('View2').setVisible(true);
```